# Prove $xe^y + ye^x =0$ has no explicit solution $y(x)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem, multivalued-functions

By the implicit function theorem there exists a solution $ y(x)$ of $$xe^y + ye^x=0$$
in a neighborhood of $ (0,0)$. Nevertheless, my textbook asks me to "observe that there is no way to write down an explicit solution $ y=y(x)$ in a neighborhood of the point $ (x_0, y_0) =(0,0)$." How can I show this?

Comment: you should take this on faith. The task of showing, conclusively, that a function cannot be written as an "elementary" function is incredibly complicated. I'm not finding a page on Ritt's algorithm, anyway : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Ritt

Comment: I agree with Will,the problem should be more clear on this. Perhaps something along the lines of "Observe that you can't write $y$ as $g(x)$" or something.

Comment: I had the wrong name, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm    Note that the word Observe just means to notice in most mathematics. I usually say "Note that"

Comment: @GitGud  it is not clear to me that the book intends this as any sort of exercise or problem. The OP may have taken this as an assignment, but i don't think the book authors meant it that way

Comment: @WillJagy But the Risch Algorithm is for finding anti-derivatives. What is the connection? I also think your interpretation (of it not being an exercise) is possible.

Comment: @GitGud that is all I could remember. CAS's do a fairly good job producing answers to, well, things, in elementary ways. I'm not sure what we should call the study of showing that an implicit function is not elementary, maybe the name Galois involved.... and robjohn came up with something

Comment: Thanks. This is from Pugh's Real Analysis. Parts of his exercises are sometimes just asking us to notice something, so you may be right. He next asks "Why, nevertheless, does there exist a $ C^{\infty}$ solution $ y=y(x)$ of $ xe^y + ye^x =0$ near $ (0,0)$"? The obvious answer is because the implicit function theorem says so-- is there anything more significant to say?

Comment: If this happens in more than one place in the book I would say it is one of his preferences. Unless he has a large section on, say, differential algebra (which may not quite cover this case anyway) I would say that you cannot be expected to prove this. I've never known how to prove such things.

Comment: $e^{y-x}+\frac{y}{x}=0$ Not in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ because it contains $(0,0)$ but yes in another point (with $xy<0$ of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no elementary function, but using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), we get
$$
y=-\operatorname{W}(xe^{-x})
$$

Comment: which has real solutions if $x\geq -1$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: actually, this has real solutions for $x\ge-\operatorname{W}\left(\frac1e\right)\doteq-0.278464542761$

Comment: Sorry for the wrong comment (I used the wrong sign) !